# For Facebook 'share' button inside an iFrame, where does it get opengraph tags?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have a site that shows a video in a popup layer... which works great, and lets me keep the videos all on one page without reloading the page. Except, if someone wants to share the video they're watching to Facebook, I can only have one thumbnail specified in the og: tags (and I can't change them on the fly with the video).

So I had an idea to show the video inside an iFrame, and then the page in the iFrame would have its og: tags set up with the right thumbnail for that video. Will Facebook use the og: tags from the iFrame, or from the parent page?

Comment: Facebook will get the OG info from the URL that is shared.

Comment: So if I am forcing the URL to the iFrame URL (which folks can click to enter, that's fine, I can redirect them back to the main site and play the video they want)... hmmm